# Check through array with wildcard value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a foreach loop and I need to iterate through it to get some data.

At the moment I have:

```
$mentioned = $tweetdata['entities']['user_mentions'][0]['screen_name'];
```

Which works but will only get one result because it is always targetting the array element `[0]`

This element has no key for me to target.

But there is often more than one element, e.g [1] and [2]

How can I do something similar to wildcard? I need to look into that key value (screen_name) but for all elements.

E.g using [*] so it will check for all?

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach loop:

```
$mentioned=array();
foreach ($tweetdata['entities']['user_mentions'] as $record)
{
     $mentioned[]=$record['screen_name'];
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't target the data inside [screen_name]

Comment: Right. @user1187347 fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Roman Sokolovskyy's answer

```
$mentioned=array();
foreach ($tweetdata['entities']['user_mentions'] as $record)
{
     $mentioned[]=$record['screen_name'];
}
```